# The variable _ is either undeclared or was never assigned error

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I've encountered this error everytime I try to open the `NewComponentForm.cs[Design]`.

I've looked up this error and everyone says that you should clean your solution and rebuild and restart the VS application. In my case it didn't help at all.

So this is some legacy code that I need to add functionality, it works by having like 5 Views in a form and just changing the `Visible` attribute with the help of some buttons, the error is:

> The variable 'LoadRemoteDescriptorsView' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

It seems that `LoadRemoteDescriptorsView` view was added manually (by code and not by the designer) to the component, because everytime I add a button or some other control the code for `LoadRemoteDescriptorsView` dissapears.

This is a snippet of the code. NOTE: the program runs fine even if I select 'Ignore and Continue' when the error pops.

```
partial class NewComponentForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.PlatformButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.EditDeviceAmplifierButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.AddDeviceToAmplifierButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.ComponentPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsView = new ExamplePlugins.DeviceMapper.View.LoadRemoteDescriptors();
        //LoadRemoteDescriptorsView = new LoadRemoteDescriptors();
        this.EditAmplifierDeviceOptionsView = new ExamplePlugins.DeviceMapper.View.EditAmplifierDeviceOptions();
        this.MainAcceptCancelButtonsPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.AcceptButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.CancelButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.NewAmplifierView = new ExamplePlugins.DeviceMapper.View.NewAmplifier();
        this.AddDeviceToAmplifierView = new ExamplePlugins.DeviceMapper.View.AddDeviceToAmplifier();
        this.NewDeviceView = new ExamplePlugins.DeviceMapper.View.NewDevice();
        this.DeviceButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnRegSettings = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.ComponentPanel.SuspendLayout();
        this.MainAcceptCancelButtonsPanel.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        /*****/
        /*****/SOME OTHER CODE HERE
        /*****/
        /*****/
        // 
        // ComponentPanel
        // 
        this.ComponentPanel.Controls.Add(this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsView); //Added
        this.ComponentPanel.Controls.Add(this.EditAmplifierDeviceOptionsView);
        this.ComponentPanel.Controls.Add(this.MainAcceptCancelButtonsPanel);
        this.ComponentPanel.Controls.Add(this.NewAmplifierView);
        this.ComponentPanel.Controls.Add(this.AddDeviceToAmplifierView);
        this.ComponentPanel.Controls.Add(this.NewDeviceView);
        this.ComponentPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(116, 2);
        this.ComponentPanel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        this.ComponentPanel.Name = "ComponentPanel";
        this.ComponentPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(803, 515);
        this.ComponentPanel.TabIndex = 4;
        //*******************************************************************************//
        // 
        // LoadRemoteDescriptorsView
        // 
        this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 0);
        this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsView.Name = "LoadRemoteDescriptorsView";
        this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(670, 318);
        this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsView.TabIndex = 8;
        this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsView.Visible = false;
        //*******************************************************************************//
        //
```

`LoadRemoteDescriptorsView` is declared early in the `InitializeComponent()` function

```
this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsView = new ExamplePlugins.DeviceMapper.View.LoadRemoteDescriptors();
```

The error points to the line when we are adding that view to the component panel

```
this.ComponentPanel.Controls.Add(this.LoadRemoteDescriptorsView); //Added
```

What am I missing out here?

Comment: This code appears to be edited by hand, in spite of the explicit "do not modify the contents of this method" warning.  And yes, that's exactly what goes wrong when you do this.  You can edit the constructor of the class.

Comment: *`LoadRemoteDescriptorsView` is declared early in the `InitializeComponent()` function* -- actually, that's where it is **initialized**.  It also needs to be [declared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) somewhere, something like `private ExamplePlugins.DeviceMapper.View.LoadRemoteDescriptors  LoadRemoteDescriptorsView;`   Usually this is done at the bottom of the `NewComponentForm.Designer.cs` partial class definition.  If somebody manually put it in another file, maybe that's causing the problem?